# How does one pick the proper loop invariant to prove an algorithm's correctness?

Tags: java, algorithm, induction, loop-invariant

We started with loop invariants last week and our professor proposed this question to work on at home. I've been following along the slides/lectures but I am having so much trouble with identifying a loop invariant which can help me prove the correctness of this algorithm.

Consider the following program which returns the least common multiple (LCM) of two natural numbers

```
// Pre : a, b are natural numbers
// Post : return LCM (a, b)
int GetLCM(int a, int b) {
    int x = a;
    int y = b;
    while (x != y) {
        if (x < y) {
            x = x + a;
        } else {
            y = y + b;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

I need to find the "proper loop invariant (Inv(x,y)) for this while-loop" which can aid me in proving its correctness. Are there multiple loop invariants which can be used to prove its correctness? I have a better understanding on proving an invariant using induction. However the initial process of picking a sufficient loop invariant(s) is confusing. If someone could lead me in the right direction or give me an example of the loop invariant in this while-loop, that would be much appreciated.

I understand that a loop invariant should be true before and immediately after every iteration of a loop. We did some word examples in class and it made a lot more sense, but when it comes to actually picking the loop invariant from some code I feel lost.

Comment: unfortunately it can be something of an art. You need to understand how the loop seems to progress some property towards completion.

Comment: What about `x=n*a and y=m*b`where `n` and `m` are natural numbers? In other words, `x` seems to be a multiple of `a` and `y` a multiple of `b`.

Comment: 1. a evenly divides x. 2. b evenly divides y. 3. x ≤ lcm(a, b). 4. y ≤ lcm(a, b). should suffice for safety (never returns the wrong lcm). Induction on 2 lcm(a, b) - (x + y) handles liveness (always returns). In general, I recommend writing down as many facts as possible that should hold invariantly and trying to assemble them into a proof.

Comment: Also x > 0 and y > 0 (and the precondition a > 0 and b > 0).

Comment: Thank you, great place for me to start I appreciate the assistance

Comment: Just to throw in a rought idea - the algorithm first copies its input (`a` and `b`) to variables (`x` and `y`) and iterates on them. Note that the algorithm terminates immediately if the input values are equal (in which case both of them are the solution). I would guess that the invariant changes `x` and `y` in such a way that their least common multiple does _not_ change. Apparently, `x` always contains a multiple of `a` and `y` always contains a multiple of `b`, which is _an_ invariant for the loop (perhaps not the one that ultimately yields the proof).

Comment: Not sure if this is useful, but the sketched invariant yields a weaker partial correctness; on termination, `x` is a multiple of `a` and `y` is a multiple of `b` and `x` equals `y`, which means that both `x` and `y` are _a common multiple_ of `a` and `b`.

Comment: The question is also discussed [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/65774/prove-correctness-of-iterative-lcm-algorithm)